# How to bind an array to a boolean in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I would like to be able to bind an array to a boolean field (I have a checkbox and a hidden field. If I don't receive any value for a field it can display default value). Spring doesn't allow that:

```
binding error Field error in object 'target' on field 'documents': rejected value [true,false]; codes [typeMismatch.target.documents,typeMismatch.documents,typeMismatch.boolean,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [target.documents,documents]; arguments []; default message [documents]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String[]' to required type 'boolean' for property 'documents'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid boolean value [true,false]]
```

I've tried to add my own property editor, but it seems that this error is thrown earlier.

```
ServletRequestDataBinder binder = new ServletRequestDataBinder(formBean);
binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"), true, 10));


binder.registerCustomEditor(Boolean.class, new PropertyEditorSupport() {
    @Override
    public void setAsText(String text) {
        logger.debug("boolean text : " + text);
        // setValue(type);
    }
});

binder.registerCustomEditor(String[].class, new PropertyEditorSupport() {
    @Override
    public void setAsText(String text) {
        logger.debug("array text : " + text);
        // setValue(type);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now my solution is to:

```
//autowire a ConversionService
@Autowired
ConversionService conversionService;
 [...]
//set a ConversionService
ServletRequestDataBinder binder = new ServletRequestDataBinder(formBean);
binder.setConversionService(conversionService);
```

Register a Converter. I'm using Spring Boot, in my case registering it as a bean works.

```
@Component
public class StringArrayToBolean implements Converter<String[], Boolean> {

    protected final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Override
    public Boolean convert(String[] source) {;
        if (source.length == 1) {
            return source[0].equals("true");
        } else if (source.length > 0) {
            for (String s : source) {
                if (s.equals("true")) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```